# CSV to XLSX VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxfOw.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6VTU.png)I am just learning VB.NET and unfortunately I have been tasked with something I do not have a clue how to do.

I need to create a quick windows based application to export csv files into an XLSX file.

Yes, I know that other posts may have a similar topic however this one I believe is unique.

The CSV file will have 5 headers, `Line, Component, Picked, Placed and Missed. We have part numbers in column 2 that would be placed under Component. I am understanding from the powers that be, this file sums the total part numbers i.e. 0-5490045 and the line JUKI 3 and totals Picked, Placed and Missed parts. I have provided a sample rows below. First row is the csv formatted, the second is the output. I am not sure which loop would be best a FOR loop, WHILE loop etc. I am assuming I will need a loop of some sort to get through all the data in the csv file.
The only code I have opens the dialog box and allows for file selection and attempts to read into a datatable. I am attempting to get this working and then restructure some code.

```
Imports Spire.Xls
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Data

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim dialog As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
        dialog.Filter="CSV document(*.csv)|*.csv"
        Dim result As DialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog
        If(result=DialogResult.OK) Then
            Dim csvFile As String = dialog.FileName
            Dim workbook As Workbook = New Workbook
            workbook.LoadFromFile(csvFile,",")
            Dim worksheet As Worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(0)
            Dim dt As DataTable=worksheet.ExportDataTable

            Me.dataGridView1.DataSource=dt
        End If
    End Sub


End Class



  JUKI 3    0-5490045 96    96  3

  Line  Component   Picked  Placed  Missed
  JUKI 3    0-5490045   99  96  3
```

Comment: You haven't really described what you've tried or where you're stuck.  What specifically is your question?  If you're just asking how to create an Excel file in .NET, there are libraries/tutorials/examples online for that.

Comment: I've been searching and haven't really found a good one. e-iceblue seems ok. It's really crazy, all that is needed is to take a csv file sum the values in columns 1-5 based upon part-number and show it in a datatable. and export it as xls.

Comment: I would suggest you split your problem into smaller ones and investigate each one then post a specific question about a smaller problem. For example, can you open a file? Can you read a file? Can you read csv? Can you store csv content? Can you read that stored content? ...

Comment: Excel will open CSV files, so what is the point of your task?

Comment: This I am aware of. These csv files are created by surface mount machines. There is too much data for the user(s) to do this manually. This is a way for the person that does the ordering to determine the number of parts that the work order called for vs the number that were actually placed on the part. So, if 300 were called for and only 250 placed, then we need to order another 50.

Comment: @the_lotus thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Sorry about all the confusion, I suck at using forums.  I have attached a screenshot of the csv file. I am not sure how to handle blank lines or lines such as line 1 and line 27. The way these dang files are created are really stupid I think. I am able to load and read the file, however I get the duplicate entry error. I believe this is coming from those lines.

Comment: As others suggest, you should break the problem down into smaller manageable pieces. Read a `csv` file, write to excel, calculate values. Your question is confusing as to what you need to accomplish. Example in the paragraph that starts _The CSV file will have 3 headers_ … doesn’t make a lot of sense. Using your sample rows example makes even less sense. The first line is the data from the `csv` file? And the next two lines are what you want to display? Other than “JUKI 3 machines” they don’t seem to match/sum/total at all? Even the part numbers look different.

Comment: Your attached link to the csv doesn’t help much either. It looks like an excel file. How are you reading it into your program? You are going to have to specify where you are having problems, reading the file, exporting the file, calculations not working properly… You are going to have to be more specific and show some code to get an answer; otherwise speculation is simply a waste of time. I suggest you examine. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Let me try this yet again. The csv file that I attached are the files I am needing to convert from csv to xls(xlsx). The headers that will be in the xls/xlsx file are as above Line, Component, Picked, Placed and Missed. What needs to happen prior to exporting is the csv file needs some magic done to it. Column 2 (Component) needs a COUNT DISTINCT added to it or something similar so that when the program comes across part 0-5490045 it keeps a running total of Picked, Placed and Missed. Then, displays that information in a datatable. I am able to load the csv file as well as read the csv file.

Comment: The issue at hand is: I am not able to successfully load the data into the datatable because of the rows like row 1 and 27 of the screenshot. I need to figure out a way of dealing with those rows. Hope this helps a little. Sorry for the long and confusing posts. Thank you for all the help and suggestions as well.

Comment: You should consider editing your original post to clarify your question as others may not see your comment. Without looking at your code that is giving you problems… again speculation is all we can offer.

Comment: I see that you posted additional code... Are you getting an error when you are taking the csv file into a datatable? Or are you now asking how to handle the data once in the datatable?

Comment: @codeMonger123 I am getting the duplicate data error. I am wanting to know how to handle the data in the csv file so that I do not get that error. I believe the error is caused by rows like row 1 and row 27 of the screenshot.

Comment: As your link shows an excel file and you are calling it a `csv` file. Granted you can easily open a `csv` file in excel, but in your button click code you set up an open file dialog that looks for `csv` files, then once the `csv` file is selected you “loadFromFile” into an new excel worksheet? From your picture, would it not be easier to simply save it as an excel file and open it instead of saving it as a `csv`? OR use a stream reader to read the `csv` file, then make the changes you want then export it back to a new excel file? Is there some reason you use the Spire.xls import?

Comment: I was using the Spire.xls as I figured this would help simplify things. Please note that I have attached the csv file in original format no edits or imports.

Comment: You attachment "pictures" are nice but useless as we can not copy them to use for testing. I usually use interop for excel. Mind if I ask how is Spire going to help simplify things? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @JohnG honestly it was the first one I came across that didn't seem to complex to use. Maybe I should look at the interop syntax. I actually forgot all about that. How can I attach the files so that you may use them for testing?

Comment: Copy and paste a small amount of your data... about the same amount as in your picture. To read a `csv` file you need nothing special... IO.StremReader will work to read `csv` files. That is why I am scratching my head trying to figure out in your button click event why you are trying to create a new excel file with the "LoadFromFile" when you already have the excel file.

Comment: In other words... In your button click event… you open a `csv` file, and read it into an excel file with “LoadFromFile”. If you open the `csv` in excel, could you not simply “SaveAs” an excel workbook and absolutely no code is needed for this step.

Comment: @JohnG yes I could do that however the user(s) want something to do this automatically. Their reason is because they need to total each distinct part number.

Comment: And there is some reason you cant do this in excel? Or do you prefer to do it in VB which I can understand as I would think it would be easier. A lot of this depends on how much data you are dealing with.

Comment: I can post a little example if you need to get started. But from what we have discussed so far and using VB or C#, I would consider making a Class for this. Let’s call it `Machines` that defines a row in your worksheet consisting of a name, partNumber, InventoryIn, InventoryOut…etc.  Then when you read the cvs/excel file you will have a convenient means of storing these `Machines` objects into a list. Once stored, you can loop through the list and do your filtering (Sums/delete/combine) to a new list. Then simply output the new list to excel. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It does make sense, however what about the rows that have data such as row 1 and row 27 of the imported csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to accomplish how to import the data into a datatable below is a fast way of handling that. This will bring your whole csv into a datatable which you could then do logic on and create your xlsx file.

```
Friend Shared Function GetExcelFile(ByVal strFileName As String, ByVal strPath As String) As DataTable

Try

    Dim dt As New DataTable

        Dim ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strPath & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\"""
        Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr)
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from " & strFileName, conn)
        da.Fill(dt)

    Return dt

Catch ex As Exception
    Return Nothing
End Try

End Function
```

Comment: So once it is imported I can then programmatically total distinct column values? How would one go about handling data such as in the first row? This would be a lot easier if the stupid machine didn't add all that unused crap.

Comment: You could. I would Prob ask that in a different question though. But as an example to get distinct values you could do data : tbl.AsDataView.ToTable(True, "Your Column").Rows.Count

Comment: JohnG - has a good point. If the only thing you are doing is putting the csv file as a xlsx file.

Comment: Thanks all, I appreciate all the help and advice.

Comment: Why even use a button. Make it a console application with batch file and have it run a as a scheduled task in windows.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to make a suggestion and not show how it would work. Below is an example using a custom object called `Machine` to hold the data. This class is a bare minimum for an object and is only used as an example to get you started. It has some fields that will come in handy when looping thru the list to do your computations. It is also here you could add some custom functions/subs to help in some task that involves “Machine” objects.  Also here you could add some compare functions which will enable you to sort among other things. After you put all this together you should end up with a list of valid `Machine` objects.

It is this list you could use to help you move on to the computing/removing duplicates part of your task. In the process of computing the data you could create a final list of `Machine` objects that you could use to export to excel with headers or display it to a DataGridView. Hope this helps.

**Machine Class**

```
Public Class Machine
  Private name As String
  Private partNumber As String
  Private inventoryIn As Integer
  Private inventoryOut As Integer
  Private inventoryMissing As Integer

  Public Sub New(inName As String, inPartNum As String, inInvIn As Integer, inInvOut As Integer, InInvMis As Integer)
    name = inName
    partNumber = inPartNum
    inventoryIn = inInvIn
    inventoryOut = inInvOut
    inventoryMissing = InInvMis
  End Sub

  Property GetName As String
    Get
      Return name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      name = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return "Name: " + name + " #: " + partNumber + vbTab + " In:" + inventoryIn.ToString() + " Out:" + inventoryOut.ToString() + " Miss:" + inventoryMissing.ToString()
  End Function
End Class
```

Now to your issue of **reading the file**

I did not use anything involving excel. Since you have a simple `csv` file we will use it. Also we will use the `Machine` class above. Using your open file dialog we get the name of the file to read.   A variable `partsList` is created to hold the `Machine` objects created when reading the file.  Then a `for each` loop goes through the list and displays the results in a text box on the form.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim dialog As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
  dialog.Filter = "CSV document(*.csv)|*.csv"
  Dim result As DialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog
  If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
    Dim csvFile As String = dialog.FileName
    Dim partsList As List(Of Machine) = ReadText(csvFile)
    For Each curMac As Machine In partsList
      TextBox1.AppendText(curMac.ToString() + Environment.NewLine)
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

**Function to read the csv file**

```
Private Function ReadText(filePath As String) As List(Of Machine)
  Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
  Dim data As List(Of Machine) = New List(Of Machine)
  fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(filePath)
  Dim curline As String = ""
  While (Not curline Is Nothing)
    curline = fileReader.ReadLine()
    '' need to check for valid data
    '' if anything is invalid simply ignore it... i.e. your bad rows
    '' keep in mind this will also ignore good rows that have a single piece of data bad
    If (StringOK(curline)) Then
      Dim newMac = GetMac(curline)
      data.Add(newMac)
    End If
  End While
  Return data
End Function
```

A couple of helper functions to validate the data

```
Private Function StringOK(inString As String) As Boolean
  If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inString)) Then
    Return False
  End If
  Dim splitArray() As String = inString.Split(",")
  Try
    If ((String.IsNullOrEmpty(splitArray(0))) Or (String.IsNullOrEmpty(splitArray(1)))) Then
      Return False
    End If
    Dim value As Integer
    If ((Not Integer.TryParse(splitArray(2), value)) Or
        (Not Integer.TryParse(splitArray(3), value)) Or
        (Not Integer.TryParse(splitArray(4), value))) Then
      Return False
    End If
    Return True
  Catch ex As Exception
    Return False
  End Try
End Function

Function GetMac(inString As String) As Machine
  Dim splitArray() As String = inString.Split(",")
  Dim value As Integer
  Dim name As String = splitArray(0)
  Dim number As String = splitArray(1)
  Integer.TryParse(splitArray(2), value)
  Dim invIn As Integer = value
  Integer.TryParse(splitArray(3), value)
  Dim invOut As Integer = value
  Integer.TryParse(splitArray(4), value)
  Dim invMis As Integer = value
  Return New Machine(name, number, invIn, invOut, invMis)
End Function
```